# OWIN, Session carry over on sub application

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, session

I'm working on a pair of angular applications hosted in ASP.Net MVC applications. On the staging environment, the sites are hosted as sub applications as such:

- some.domain.com/app_one
- some.domain.com/app_two

The problem is that the session from one is available to the other. But since they are using different structures for the user data, so the other application recognize an available session but not the data in it.

The two applications provide different functionality to different user bases and users of the one should in general be blocked from the other. Since the session is shared though it would be possible for a user of one to log in and get an authentication token and then provide it in a request to the other who would then deem the token valid. We would want the sessions to be independent and separate from each other.

We're using both `OAuthBearerAuthentication` and `CookieAuthentication`.

So far I've tried setting different realms for the `OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions`, but that didn't resolve the issue.

This is the code we're using in the OWIN configuration:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Realm = "app_one"
    };
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer,
        CookieName = "app_one",
        LoginPath = new PathString("/#/login")
    });

    app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer);
}
```

We're also using local storage to store the authentication token. Local storage is also available between the sub applications. Is it possible to include the folder part in the domain when determining which local storage to use?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't explain what your expectations are nor is there a specific question here. Authentication is not trivial....be more specific